# Zeep: got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, soap-client

Im trying to do the call to external server but has an error:

```
TypeError: {http://tempuri.org/}waybill() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WAYBILL'. Signature: `_value_1: ANY`
```

Here is the code:

```py
soap_client = zeep.Client(wsdl=WAYBILL_SERVICE_URL)
waybill = {
        "type":2,
        "goods_list":[
            {
                "w_name":"test",
                "w_id":2
            }
        ],
        "trans_id":1
    }
soap_client.service.save_waybill(su=service_user.username, sp=service_user.password, waybill={"WAYBILL": waybill})
```

This is a raw request that works well:

```xml
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <save_waybill xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <su>test</su>
            <sp>test</sp>
            <waybill>
                <WAYBILL>
                    <GOODS_LIST>
                        <GOODS>
                            <W_NAME>test</W_NAME>
                            <W_ID>2</W_ID>
                        </GOODS>
                    </GOODS_LIST>
                    <TYPE>2</TYPE>
                    <TRANS_ID>1</TRANS_ID>
                </WAYBILL>
            </waybill>
        </save_waybill>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How to make my code do the same that that request do? Sorry I'm new in soap.